# Alternative to simulink transparent subsystem

Tags: simulink

I need to organize a set of elements in simulink. The first method is to create a subsystem. The problem with subsystem is that the elements inside it are no longer visible. An alternative method is to create a colorized box and put it behind a set of elements as a background. It makes a lot of troubles during selection of elements.

The ideal method is to have a subsystem which is transparent but you can see the elements inside it. So you can make it large and see inside it without opening it.

What is the feasible alternative method?

[image]

Comment: There isn't.  You've covered the available options.

Comment: @PhilGoddard It is so sad :(

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that there is no support by simulink doing this, the only possibility would be to use a mask icon which shows the content. The following is a very rough prototype for the mask code:

```
model='s1/Subsystem';
loc=fullfile(pwd,[model,'.png']);
print(['-s' model], ['-dpng'], '-r300', loc);
image(loc);
port_label('input',1,'In1');
port_label('output',1,'Out1');
```

[image]

Obviously this prototype has multiple issues which must be addressed when really using the code:

- Remove the hard-coded directory.
- Set in- and outports automatically.
- create required folder structure. (folder s1 must be created once manually)
- Scale the subsystem block to make the image look good
- work properly if pwd is not the directory the model is stored in

Comment: Thanks Daniel. If I update the subsystem, does it update the mask image?

Comment: I did not test that, I only know that resizing triggers an update. My answer is far from being complete, I guess it would take me 2-3 hours of work to complete this to a good working solution. Wasn't willing to invest that time, but at least wanted to share the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the 'Icon Drawing Commands' of the mask parameter's tab 'Icon and Ports' :-

1. Take a screenshot of the logic gates you want to be visible on the subsystem (the ones with a blue background color shown in your question)
2. Save the picture e.g 'mylogic.png'
3. Write this command in the 'Icon Drawing Command' field of Icon and Ports image(imread('Pause_Icon.png'));

You're done. But yes, make sure you have the picture file in the same folder as your model or simply add the folder containing the picture on your path.

Of course, if you update the blocks inside the subsystem, you'll have to update the mask icon with the new screenshot.